# Parse JSON Data into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, rss

I'm using the Google Feeds API to display the latest posts from my Facebook.

The statues are coming from an XML file from fbrss.com and this code I have below successfully works:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("feeds", "1")

    $.ajax({
        url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=3&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('feedhere.xml'),
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function (data) {
            if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
                $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                    console.log("------------------------");
                    console.log("postContent     : " + e.title);
                    console.log("link    : " + e.link);
                    console.log("date:      " + e.publishedDate);

                });
                ;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The response I get from console, as expected

```
    postContent     : Example post, just testing our facebook news right now!
link    : https://www.facebook.com/LINKTOPOST
date:      Fri, 04 Apr 2014 23:54:02
------------------------
postContent     : We're getting ready to launch our new website! Stay tuned for more updates and more info. We're very excited.
link    : https://www.facebook.com/LINKTOPOST
date:      Fri, 04 Apr 2014 23:06:59 -0700
```

Now I've tried appending the jsonData to a div like so, but I don't think I was doing it correctly.

```
 if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
                $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                    window.NewsPost = e.title;
                    console.log("------------------------");
                    console.log("postContent     : " + e.title);
                    console.log("link    : " + e.link);
                    console.log("date:      " + e.publishedDate);

                });
                                }

            $("#facebookrss").append("<div>Test" + NewsPost +"</div>");

        }
    });
```

I assigned a global variable so I could use it outside of that. But I'm not getting anything inside my #facebookrss div.

I'm trying to have the date and postcontent into seperate divs, with the postcontent being wrapped in the link so they can visit the facebook page.

I also am trying to parse the date as "MM - DD". The Google Feeds API doesn't seem very well fleshed out, but I'm also very new to javascript.

Thanks so much to anyone who can help whatsoever.

EDIT: HAVE SUCCESSFULLY SOLVED IT, THANK YOU CACKHAROT. BELOW IS MY FINAL CODE FITTING INTO FORMATTING AND INCLUDES BETTER FORMATTED DATE.

```
$.ajax({
        url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=3&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('feedhere.xml'),
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function (data) {
            if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
                $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                    window.NewsPost = e.title;
                    console.log("------------------------");
                    console.log("postContent     : " + e.title);
                    console.log("link    : " + e.link);
                    console.log("date:      " + e.publishedDate);
                    // construct div tag to have the new post details

                    var date = new Date(e.publishedDate);
                    monthNames =
                        [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ];
                    datemonth = monthNames[ date.getMonth() ];
                    dateday = date.getDay();

                    var construct_news = '<div class="facebook-feed">';
                    construct_news += '<div class="left">';
                    construct_news += '<div class="footer-circle-large">';
                    construct_news +='<div class="month">' + datemonth + '</div>';
                    construct_news += '<div class="day">' + dateday + '</div>';
                    construct_news += '</div>';
                    construct_news += '</div>';
                    construct_news += '<div class="right">';

                    construct_news += '<div>';
                    construct_news += '<span class="facebook-update"><a target="_blank" href="'+ e.link+'">' + e.title + '</a></span>';

                    construct_news += '</div>';
                    construct_news += '</div>';
                    construct_news += '</div>';

                    $("#facebookrss").append(construct_news); // append it to rss div

                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried storing it into variable then using something such as .html("Test" + postContentVar);

Comment: So add that code to your question and explain what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing

Comment: updated with an example I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
    $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        window.NewsPost = e.title;
        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("postContent     : " + e.title);
        console.log("link    : " + e.link);
        console.log("date:      " + e.publishedDate);
        // construct div tag to have the new post details

        var new_post_tag = '<div>';
        new_post_tag += '<h4>' + e.title + '</h4>';
        new_post_tag += '<p>' + e.link + '</p>';
        new_post_tag += '<p>' + e.publishedDate + '</p>';
        new_post_tag += '</div>';

        $("#facebookrss").append(new_post_tag); // append it to rss div
    });
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! what's funny is your approach doesn't seem all too different what I tried. Actually, i put yours in and it didn't work at first. I tried removing a span element from #facebookrss then it was working. Does append only work on empty elements or something?

Comment: Also, if I can parse the date into a mm-dd format, do I really need to create an array with month names or does jquery have an easier solution?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Nevermind, Ifigured that one out myself. I had to edit it a bit for my styling of course. But I have updated the OP with my solution in case anyone needs help on the same thing.